# EKEventViewController shows strange dark background

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, eventkit

Basically I have a tableView in my viewController showing some calendar events and upon clicking a row I want to show the default EKEventViewController that presents the event in a standard way.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let eventViewController = EKEventViewController()
    eventViewController.event = lastEvents[indexPath.row]
    eventViewController.allowsCalendarPreview = true
    show(eventViewController, sender: nil)
}
```

This works, however there's a strange dark background that appears "under" this EKEventViewController. I have to get rid of this background.

I've uploaded an [example application](https://github.com/gubikmic/EKEventViewController-StrangeBackground) that exhibits this behavior.

Additionally, after the EKEventViewController has been shown and popped, there remains a bar at the bottom (where the "Delete Event" button was).

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that there's a debug message telling me `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` However it's strange since it's not really my layout. All I'm doing is showing this viewController.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

I have not looked at your project. However, the event view controller expects to be in a navigation controller. I assume you're adding it to a navigation controller. Otherwise, how are you getting the back button? Anyway, I think it's the properties of the navigation controller you need to look at.

I get constraint warnings in the debugger as well. That's how I found your question - I was looking to see if others had discussed the constraint warnings. Documentation does not seem to say anything about setting up or editing constraints.